# Learning IDAT in detail

Tags: image, png, file-format

I have a broken png file where compression CMF is 0x28 and FLG is 0xB5 in the IDAT chunk. As far as i know it shouldn't be a valid IDAT header. Can anyone tell me if this CMF and FLG byte is valid?If possible, please give a source from where I can see the breakdown of every type of IDAT chunk in detail.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. `0x28b5` is not a multiple of 31. E.g., `0x28b0` would be valid.

That is not the IDAT header. That is the start of the IDAT contents. The first two bytes are, or are supposed to be, a zlib header. The contents of the concatenation of the contents of all of the IDAT chunks in a PNG file is one zlib stream. You can find the zlib wrapper documented in [RFC 1950](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1950), and the deflate compressed data contained in the zlib wrapper documented in [RFC 1951](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1951).

Comment: Actually I am fixing a file. I tried 0x28b0 but while reading the file zlib is getting an error. The starting bytes of IDAT chunk in my file is 28 b0 2f fd a0 20 4f. I changed the b5 to b0. Still zlib is getting error from the byte 20. I can't understand why

Comment: Obviously your png file is corrupted.